# Jersey Expires Header not working

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey bundle 1.11 to provide some RESTful web service.

Each time I browse a REST resource with Chrome, I notice that there's an HTTP Header Expires set to **Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET**.

I tried to edit the Response adding:

```
return Response.ok( myObject ).expires(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000)).build();
```

Unfortunately, this adds another HTTP Header Expires instead of replacing the old one.

What is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: header is not added by default anywhere, there must be some other logic or maybe its added by your container - check its settings/documentation..

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I am seeing the exact same behaviour. The container here is JBoss 4.2.3. This is a PUT method with BASIC authentication. My response is generated thus:

```
Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + lifetime);
return Response.noContent().expires(exp).build();
```

When invoked with cURL, these are the returned headers:

```
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Pragma: No-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
< X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (...
< Expires: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 11:08:54 GMT
< Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 11:08:24 GMT
<
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to prevent your browser from caching of the requested resource.
The date itself is the timestamp with zero seconds, the begin of the UNIX era.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my app server (In this case JBoss 4.2.3.GA) would not allow Jersey to overwrite the header this way.

To workaround:

1. Inject the response object into the method using a parameter:

   > @Context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response
2. Set the header on the response object rather than using .expires() :

   > response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 14400000);

I used #2 before I called .build() on the ResponseBuilder, not sure if it makes a difference or not when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My workaround is:

1. Inject the response

   `@Context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response`
2. Reset the response object

   `response.reset();`
3. Use the ResponseBuilder to set the headers.

   `return Response
       .ok(icon.getData())
       .type(icon.getContentType())
       .expires(cal.getTime())
       .build();`